# Adding some time to the "onmouseover" tag in HTML

Tags: html, css, onmouseover

How can I add some time to the "onmouseover" tag in HTML?

What I want is when the user moves the mouse pointer over a certain "div" it should appear. And when the mouse leaves the "div" that "div" should disappear. This is what I have done so far.

But I need that when the mouse leaves the "div" that "div" must disappears after e.g. 5 sec. How can I do it?

I cant share my code right now, but there is an example jsfiddle.net/AdamMartin121/pk3EB When the mouse pointer located inside red borders it shows a photo, when the pointer is outside, the photo disappears immediately, but I need a disappearance of the photo after some time

Comment: share what you have done so far??

Comment: Don't use inline JS...create a proper JS function and call it `onmouseover` woudl be an option

Comment: Mouseover is not a tag, it is an event attribute.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai Unfortunately I cant share my code right now, but there is an example http://jsfiddle.net/AdamMartin121/pk3EB/ When the mouse pointer located inside red borders it shows a photo, when the pointer is outside, the photo disappears immediately, but I need a disappearance of the photo after some time

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use jquery and setTimeOut function:

```
$('#yourdiv').mouseleave(function() {
     setTimeout(function () {
        $('#yourdiv').hide();
    }, 5000);
```

Comment: jQuery just for that?

Comment: not mendatory, just a suggestion without seeing his code. 
After adding the jsfiddle, I can suggest changing hidePop() function in this manner:

`function hidePop() {
    setTimeout(function(){pop.style.visibility = 'hidden'}, 3000);
}`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with CSS.

HTML:

```
<div class="holder">
    <div class="hovered">same text</div>
    <div class="popup">same text</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.holder{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:20px;
}

.hovered{
    float:left;
    padding:5px;
    background:green;
}

.popup{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:100%;
    left:100%;
    background:red;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease;
    transition: all 300ms ease;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 3s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 3s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 3s;
    -o-transition-delay: 3s;
    transition-delay: 3s;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.hovered:hover+.popup{
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0;
    -ms-transition-delay: 0;
    -o-transition-delay: 0;
    transition-delay: 0;
    opacity:1;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a66euaLq/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It also works fine, but the variant with jQuery more shorter

Comment: Yes, it more shorter, but variant with CSS is faster and don't need JS files.

Comment: @emdroof Don't forget to take into account the length of the whole jQuery library when saying it's shorter. I'd always go for the pure CSS solution where possible. Otherwise, plain JS.

Answer (score 0):

Can't believe you will use jQuery just for that.

CSS approach would be much faster and optimized. Still, if you want the JS-way, just changing your onmouseout function will work:

```
obj.onmouseout = function(){
    setTimeout(hidePop, 5000);
};
```

Just that. No need to load a huge library for something you're already doing (just without the timeout).

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/pk3EB/45/

Next step would be introducing the state of the popup so that you don't get weird behaviour when rapidly hovering/unhovering the obj div.